# Change row height of ListView programmatically in Android app

Tags: java, android, listview

I am developing an Android app with ListView.

I would like to change row height programmatically such as the height of row 0 is 100, the one of others is 200.

I am writing down the following code, however at the line **"layoutParams.height = 100;"** I encounter **NullPointerException**.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (mInflater == null){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_detail, null);
    }
    if (imageLoader == null) imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    if(position==0){
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = convertView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = 100;
        convertView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
    else{
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = convertView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = 200;
        convertView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    ・・・

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat and, btw, you're not checking if position is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter xml, change the layout height of your parent, and you will be good to go.